# Twilio clicktocall-csharp - Internal 500 Error after first launch

Tags: c#, twilio

After setting the correct "TwilioAccountSID" , "TwilioAuthToken" , and "TwilioNumber" the web page says "There was a problem calling you - please try again later." I can use other Twilio functions in other apps but the ClickToCall is not working. It will not dial out to either number.

**Example Project:** https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/clicktocall-csharp

[image: Error Message]

**Console Log in Firefox:**

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented
>   instead. jquery-1.10.2.js:5375:28 XML Parsing Error: no root element
>   found Location:
>   http://localhost:57471/01d55b0057f14d8aa4f39e67f234bae7/browserLinkSignalR/abort?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAA9nnpT%2Bd2GEGGBvJN2iSr%2FAAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAA5C0avgoOxzy0g8wtuZzNLaBQla80xMib%2FzC%2Ft9UuALwAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAAVgVKnWONXBwpQ%2FQynRYyeKOOZw8ZnvXuTf7SIoOTAGDAAAAD7kYmTiT%2FoNJJMIKh5KrXfhkyBndCsBDP4QnpepbcwWc6o30MXPHYCyAiJwt2Dy2pAAAAAQWB%2BSLeKghpSzeaKqUHL7LVhQ8%2FfLiCtjRL9V%2BL03xElOpifAfuaJ2NzMxckwj2z3BoQ%2BCb7lW9A6zBQMPSXGQ%3D%3D&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1430%2F&browserName=Firefox&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+WOW64%3B+rv%3A54.0)+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F54.0
>   Line Number 1, Column 1: abort:1:1 POST XHR
>   http://localhost:1430/CallCenter/Call [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server
>   Error 18ms] Headers POST Response Call Stack
>   Cache-ControlprivateContent-Length12174Content-Typetext/html;
>   charset=utf-8DateTue, 22 Aug 2017 17:26:58
>   GMTServerMicrosoft-IIS/10.0X-AspNet-Version4.0.30319X-Powered-ByASP.NETX-SourceFiles=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcUmhvZGVzXERvd25sb2Fkc1xjbGlja3RvY2FsbC1jc2hhcnAtbWFzdGVyICgxKVxjbGlja3RvY2FsbC1jc2hhcnAtbWFzdGVyXENsaWNrVG9DYWxsLldlYlxDYWxsQ2VudGVyXENhbGw=?=
>   Acceptapplication/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01Accept-Encodinggzip,
>   deflateAccept-Languageen-US,en;q=0.5Connectionkeep-aliveContent-Length52Content-Typeapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8Hostlocalhost:1430Refererhttp://localhost:1430/User-AgentMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/54.0X-Requested-WithXMLHttpRequest

**Line Break 67:**

[image]

**Computer Log:**

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 8/24/2017 11:53:34 AM 
Event time (UTC): 8/24/2017 3:53:34 PM 
Event ID: 9b90d28d894f41a09a832ce672308828 
Event sequence: 13 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131480635887199949 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Users\Rhodes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\clicktocall-csharp-master\ClickToCall.Web\ 
    Machine name: DEV-103 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 74140 
    Process name: iisexpress.exe 
    Account name: DEV-103\Rhodes 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ClickToCall.Web.Controllers.CallCenterController.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<IsProduction>b__0(String domain) in C:\Users\Rhodes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\clicktocall-csharp-master\ClickToCall.Web\Controllers\CallCenterController.cs:line 68
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at ClickToCall.Web.Controllers.CallCenterController.IsProduction() in C:\Users\Rhodes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\clicktocall-csharp-master\ClickToCall.Web\Controllers\CallCenterController.cs:line 68
   at ClickToCall.Web.Controllers.CallCenterController.GetUri(String salesNumber) in C:\Users\Rhodes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\clicktocall-csharp-master\ClickToCall.Web\Controllers\CallCenterController.cs:line 54
   at ClickToCall.Web.Controllers.CallCenterController.<Call>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Rhodes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\clicktocall-csharp-master\ClickToCall.Web\Controllers\CallCenterController.cs:line 46
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:1430/CallCenter/Call 
    Request path: /CallCenter/Call 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: DEV-103\Rhodes 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 8 
    Thread account name: DEV-103\Rhodes 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at ClickToCall.Web.Controllers.CallCenterController.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<IsProduction>b__0(String domain) in C:\Users\Rhodes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\clicktocall-csharp-master\ClickToCall.Web\Controllers\CallCenterController.cs:line 68
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at ClickToCall.Web.Controllers.CallCenterController.IsProduction() in C:\Users\Rhodes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\clicktocall-csharp-master\ClickToCall.Web\Controllers\CallCenterController.cs:line 68
   at ClickToCall.Web.Controllers.CallCenterController.GetUri(String salesNumber) in C:\Users\Rhodes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\clicktocall-csharp-master\ClickToCall.Web\Controllers\CallCenterController.cs:line 54
   at ClickToCall.Web.Controllers.CallCenterController.<Call>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Rhodes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\clicktocall-csharp-master\ClickToCall.Web\Controllers\CallCenterController.cs:line 46
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**Ngrok Tunnel Running:**

[image: full setup]

Comment: Do you get any logs on the server for this error? It is likely to be the server that is causing the issue in this case.

Comment: I am running it locally on my machine before I adopt the code and deploy it to the server. I have reached out to Twilio about their demo project with no avail. I followed their guide to a "T". In other parts of our code, I have the Make outgoing calls and texts working no problem with the same tokens and phone numbers.

Comment: I work for Twilio and would like to fix this for you. If you are running this locally can you see the server logs? If so, can you update your question with an example of the server log when you get an error, please?

Comment: I have added the Log from today when I got the error again.

Comment: Ok, just to preface, I'm not a C# developer and don't have a development environment. However, that error says the issue is on [line 68 of the CallCenterController](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/clicktocall-csharp/blob/master/ClickToCall.Web/Controllers/CallCenterController.cs#L68). Can you debug at that point and try to find out what `origin` is set to? Perhaps you are not getting anything from the header.

Comment: I edited the question with the post back debugger log

Comment: Hey, so that's just saying the same as your original error log. There is something wrong on line 68 of the CallCenterController. Can you try to find out what `orgin` is set to on line 67? Can you set a break point in Visual Studio to inspect the variables within that function?

Comment: It's Globally declared on line 14 as: private const string OriginHeader = "Origin";

Comment: Sort of, I was actually after `origin` which is the result of calling `Request.Headers[OriginHeader]` on line 67.

Comment: I just updated the post to show the line break

Comment: You broke on line 66. We need to break after line 67 so that we can see what `origin` got set to. It's definitely `null` before it's assigned.

Comment: Line 67: "origin" is returning "null" for the breakpoint

Comment: So that's the problem then. What web server are you running this with? Why might there not be an `Origin` header set?

Comment: I am running this locally on my machine with visual studios 2017 Debugger before I adopt the code to our website. I added the required tokens and am running it from visual studios in FireFox. I have tried Microsoft Edge and Google Chome as well. Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit

Comment: Hope you've seen below, my fabulous colleague David has added the instructions you need. Sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: Please see the post for the last picture I added. I am running Ngrok tunnel and tried both ways that you detailed and am still getting the 500 Internal Server Error. As previously stated I can use other Twilio functions in different apps with the same keys no problem. I actually did use the readme at the beginning and installed and ran Ngrok but it was still not working. I even tried opening the Url that Ngrok generates and still got the error.Thank you both for your help so far. I think it is something pretty small but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: In your last picture, you are using the localhost url, can you try again with the ngrok URL?

Comment: I updated the picture to show that i am trying with both URLs

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have to leave this to @dprothero as I am out of my depth in C# now.

Comment: Thank you @philnash for your help so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rody, I'm a Twilio Developer educator and we work on the docs and those tutorials, specifically.

You helped us uncover a bug in the solution! We assumed Origin header would be passed, but apparently, [FireFox doesn't send it for AJAX requests](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446344). We have adapted the solution to look for a "PublicUrl" AppSetting so the app knows where your app is publicly hosted and can send the right URL to Twilio.

Pull down the latest version of the repository and update your `ClickToCall.Web\Local.config` to include the "PublicUrl" setting with your ngrok URL (no trailing slash). I've documented this in the README and there's an example in `ClickToCall.Web\Local.config.example`.

Another possible reason others might this issue is if you are running locally but using "localhost" instead of ngrok. In short, here's all you need to do:

**Option 1**: Command Line

1. Download and install [ngrok](https://ngrok.com)
2. Run this command to start your tunnel:
   `ngrok http 1430 -host-header="localhost:1430"`
3. This will create a unique ngrok url, looking something like: `8da2afef.ngrok.io`
4. Run the app from Visual Studio, so it's listening.
5. Open that ngrok URL in your browser and test the app.

**Option 2**: Visual Studio Extension

1. Download and install [ngrok Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions)
2. In Visual Studio, with the ClickToCall solution open, choose the "Tools" menu and select "Start ngrok Tunnel"
3. This will create a unique ngrok url, looking something like: `8da2afef.ngrok.io`
4. Run the app from Visual Studio, so it's listening.
5. Open that ngrok URL in your browser and test the app.

Please accept our apologies for the confusing documentation.

Comment: I am running Ngrok tunnel and tried both ways that you detailed and am still getting the 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Make sure you are running the app in your browser using the ngrok URL and not localhost.

Comment: if you see the last image on my post I am running it it both local host and the ngrok URL and getting the error on both.

Comment: Interesting. It works in Chrome. I noticed in your screenshot you were using FireFox and I was able to reproduce the error. FireFox isn't sending the Origin header for some reason. I will work on a fix. Related: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=446344

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try in Chrome. I guess I will need to wait for the fix before I can adapt the code for our website because we have to run all browsers.

Comment: OK, pushed up a fix. https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/clicktocall-csharp/commit/e029d8da793132e6981acc0a3c741a64df431535 I will update the answer.